# Composer manage multiple github-auth tokens?

Tags: github, composer-php

Are there any PHP extension sellers among you?
If so, do you offer archives by version only and/or do you also use a private Composer repository?

I would like to avoid using packagist which is paid.

I am increasingly confronted with PHP extension editors who use a private git repository, and we can quickly find ourselves with several "github-oauth" tokens for different reasons to indicate in our `auth.json`.

Unfortunately, Composer only allows one "github-oauth" token.
And in my opinion, managing your applications via Composer is essential.

How do you handle this situation?

I think ideally it would be to consolidate all these repositories on a GitHub account so that you only need a "github-oauth" token, but in practice it can be complicated. But this solution does not completely suit me because it is possible that in the near future I will offer extensions for sale myself.

Otherwise, I saw that there is the possibility of managing your deposit with for example Satis, but in my situation I fear that it will be oversized.